# How to retrieve information from PHP and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am interested to retrieve the name and the email of the user from my contact form and use it to display something like this: "Thank you for your message $name, we will reply to the following email: $email" I want to make changes to the .done function

Here is the javascript:

```
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sendemail.php",
        data: {
            Name: $form.find("input[name='name']").val(),
            Subject: $form.find("input[name='subject']").val(),
            Email: $form.find("input[name='email']").val(),
            message: $form.find("textarea[name=message]").val(),
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.append(form_status.html('<p style="font-weight:bold;color:white;"><i class="fa fa-spinner w3-text-white w3-spin" style="font-size:50px"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());



        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        //here is the function i want to insert the information 
        form_status.html('<p style="color:white;" class="text-success w3-animate-fading"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x" aria-hidden ="true"></i>\n\
     Message sent. Thank you for contacting us phpName, we will reply to the following email: phpEmail <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  </p>')
                .delay(7000).fadeOut();



    });
```

Comment: how does your `sendemail.php` responses? what does the page output?

Comment: Share your `sendemail.php` too please

Comment: You don't need to get the values from PHP. You already have them in your JS. e.g. `$form.find("input[name='email']").val()`. Just use that.

Comment: .done(function (data) - data holds all the returned data from your PHP page. So on your PHP page you need to return the data you want and then you can access like data.name and data.email

Comment: You're already doing this at lines 5 and 7. Those lines get the data you want!

Comment: So obviously he didnt write any of this, its all copied from somewhere and he did not even bother to try and understand it. So why should we bother to understand it for you

Comment: @SteevePitis you don't need the php file sinece I have the php data on lines 5 and 7. Does anyone know how to use them in the .done function?

Comment: here is the website: http://webdominar.xyz

Comment: Probably most people commenting here know how to use these values in the .done function. But as @RiggsFolly said, you haven't put even a minimal effort into understanding how the script you have copied and pasted works. This is just basic string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var name = $form.find("input[name='name']").val();
var email = $form.find("input[name='email']").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "sendemail.php",
    data: {
        Name: name,
        Subject: $form.find("input[name='subject']").val(),
        Email: email,
        message: $form.find("textarea[name=message]").val(),
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        form.append(form_status.html('<p style="font-weight:bold;color:white;"> < i class = "fa fa-spinner w3-text-white w3-spin" style = "font-size:50px" > < /i>Email is sending... < /p>').fadeIn());
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    //here is the function i want to retrieve the data from php
    form_status.html('<p style="color:white;" class="text-success w3 - animate - fading "><i class="fa fa - check fa - 2 x " aria-hidden ="true "></i>\n\
            Message sent. Thank you for contacting us ' + name + ', we will reply to your email shortly. <i class="fa fa - smile - o fa - 2 x " aria-hidden="true "></i></p>')
        .delay(7000).fadeOut();
});
```

Since you already have the name and email information in the form I dont understand why you just dont use that. You dont even need to ask for that information from the server. However I suggest that in the sendemail.php file you return an object containing status if the email could be sent or not. This way you can display an error message if something went wrong serverside. For instance like this:

```js
{
    success: true,
    message: '',
    errorCode: ''
}
```

Comment: so all I wanted to do is call a variable to make it simpler